# fill a complex matrix from a double

Tags: c, casting

I have a double matrix and I want its elements to pass them to a complex matrix.
I want to use casting.
For example for every even elements of double matrix I fill the real part of the complex matrix and for every odd elements ,the imaginary.

I am trying the below code but I have no result for complex matrix (all elements are zero).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{

    double re,im;
}
myComplex;

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {

    int N=2;
    double * theDouble=(double*)malloc(2*N*N*sizeof(double));

    for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<N;j++){
            theDouble[i*N+j]=i+j;
        }
    }

    for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<N;j++){
            printf("\nmydouble=%f\t",theDouble[i*N+j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    myComplex * theComplex;
    theComplex= (myComplex *)malloc(N*N*sizeof(myComplex));

    //theDouble= (double *)theComplex;

    for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<N;j++){
            theComplex[i*N+j].re=theDouble[(i*N+j)*2];

        }
    }

    //fill imaginary part
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<N;j++){
            theComplex[i*N+j].im=theDouble[(i*N+j)*2+1];

        }
    }

    for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<N;j++){
            printf("\nComplex_real=%f\t",theComplexPtr[i*N+j].re);
        printf("\nComplex_imag=%f\t",theComplexPtr[i*N+j].im);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


    return 0;     
}
```

Also,is there a faster (better) way to do this ? (with casting).

Comment: Faster perhaps not, but why don't you use the standard complex types that modern C provides? They have the advantage of implementing all arithmetic directly and also having math functions that work with complex. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: The code you've included doesn't compile (you define `theDoubl` and use `theDouble`; you define `theComplex` but use `theComple` once).  What is your real code?

Comment: perhaps, `theDouble= (double *)theComplex;` not need.

Comment: What's the purpose of this line: `theDouble= (double *)theComplex;`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're thinking of with the last assignment in `myComplex * theComplex; theComplex= (myComplex *)malloc(N*N*sizeof(myComplex)); theDouble= (double *)theComplex;` but you've leaked the original `theDouble` allocation and you're now trying to treat that data differently — very peculiar.  Remove that line and you get sane behaviour.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments.I corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create the data for a `myComplex` matrix of size N x N, the number of doubles has to be 2 x N x N.

If I understand you correctly, the data for the i-th row and j-th column of the complex matrix are at positions (i*N+j)*2 and (i*N+j)*2+1 in the double array.

Also, as others have already pointed out, remove the line `theDouble= (double *)theComplex;`.

Comment: @R Sahu:Ok , that did it.But I can't uderstand why it has to be 2*N*N.Because the elements of double are 4.The elements of complex are still 4.Also,while I am filling theComplex, it fills one time the correct results and one time zero results.

Comment: @George, there are two doubles in each myComplex. The size of each myComplex is 2 times the size of double, i.e. sizeof(myComplex) == 2*sizeof(double).

Comment: @R Sahu:Ok,itdepends how you want to use it I think.And I think  the opposite is true.Size of double =2 size of complex.